# SQL SSRS SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in column like PERM12234, PERM7685. It is combination of text and integer. I want only integer part of it.

Example I like to select only 12234 from PERM12234.

Thanks In advance

Comment: If it always starts with PERM than you could use substring(myColumn,5).

Comment: Is there same string before every integer?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Substring function to get numbers from a string

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)  = 'abcd123456'

select substring(@str,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str ),len(@str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring function:
it will work only if your column value always start witn PERM

```
select substring(columnname,5,len(columnname)-4)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
 DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)  SELECT LEFT(@str, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @str )) AS Number,
   LTRIM(RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @str ))) As Alpha
```

or

```
SELECT (@str, 5) AS Number;
```